# Why does jQuery.ajax not return JSON in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to loop through an array in javaScript with array values passed at the end of an variable called "url" so it can retrieve the corresponding JSON from a site. However it returns {"Error:","Not Found", "Status:", 404, "message"}

```
   for( var b = 0; b<all.length; b++){

    $.ajax({
         url:url+all[b],
         type:'GET',
         connectionType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         async:false,
         dataType:'jsonp',
         success:function(data){
         data = JSON.stringify(data);
         alert(data);     

         }
     });
   }
```

if I run it like this it works

```
   for( var b = 0; b<all.length; b++){

    $.ajax({
         url:url+'sammyb123',
         type:'GET',
         connectionType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         async:false,
         dataType:'jsonp',
         success:function(data){
         data = JSON.stringify(data);
         alert(data);     

         }
     });
   }
```

& if I test the all[b] seperately it returns the correct value within the array. It does not work only when it gets ran as shown in the first snippet of code. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong so I can correct the problem.

the value of url is https://wind-bow.hyperdev.space/twitch-api/streams/ 
I am building a twitch tv app

Comment: have you tried to create a new `var url` inside the for-loop to assign value: `url+all[b]` and then print it for each loop? what is the result then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, I tried it on my end and it worked. You may have a syntax error in your array declaration.

```
var all = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var url = 'https://wind-bow.hyperdev.space/twitch-api/streams/';

   for( var b = 0; b<all.length; b++){

    $.ajax({
         url:url+all[b],
         type:'GET',
         connectionType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         async:false,
         dataType:'jsonp',
         success:function(data){
         data = JSON.stringify(data);
         alert(data);     

         }
     });
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

is your `url` integer? well if it is so then maybe converting it to string first will work. Try `url:url+all[b].toString()`

Comment: the url is actually a string. I just added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: can you do a demo test for each loop, checking the value of CONCATENATED URL? what will it result? also check the data types.

Comment: the url works, you can plugin one of the array items directly url:url+"OgamingSC2" and it will work just fine